# Pass arguments from iphone to php page

Tags: php, iphone, sql, objective-c, asihttprequest

the problem i am face right now is i can't pass a variable from iphone to php page.First i want to pass the country name to php page from iphone.

This is the php code:

```
$coname=$_POST["c_name"];

    $con = mysql_connect("url","username","password");
        if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
            mysql_select_db("Appiness", $con);

    header("Content-Type: text/xml");    
    $bilgi= mysql_query("SELECT age,wname,slid,sex FROM user WHERE user.c_name='".$coname."'");
    while($sutun= mysql_fetch_array($bilgi))
    {
        echo $sutun["age"];
        echo $sutun["wname"];
        echo $sutun["sex"];        
        echo $sutun["slid"];    
    } 

    mysql_close($con);
```

this is the part i 've call the php page in xcode

```
 NSString *country=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"namecountry"];
//url's
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.trevesstudios.com/get.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:country forKey:@"c_name"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];

response = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

Can anyone help me for why this code is not working btw when i try to change the WHERE c_name='France' it works the the problem is the variable.Can anybody helpme?

Comment: Before write any codes how u r sending to Php page , so that we can find whether u r sending right way

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint after "request startSynchronous" and see how the request actually looks like. You could as well log the output in the PHP file and see what the $_REQUEST variable contains. You might want to add some escaping to the variable since you'd be vulnerable to SQL injection if not.

Comment: @Karthikeyan i am sending with asihhtprequest you can see [request setPostValue:country forKey:@"c_name"]; this line is sending part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. what is `country` value after reading it from `NSUserDefaults`?
2. what does `NSLog(@"%@",response);` print out?
3. in your PHP, what is `$coname`?
4. is `$_POST` defined? is `$_GET` defined? could you print out `$_REQUEST` content (`print_r($_REQUEST)`)?

EDIT:

can you put this statement

```
echo print_r($_REQUEST);
```

before `$coname=$_POST["c_name"];`?

can you add this statement:

```
 echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";
```

after executing `mysql_query`?

what does it output?

EDIT2:

With the `echo`es we added above, we now know that the post parameter is arriving at the server. Are you sure that there are data stored for France in your database? mysql_error did not return any error (0: in the output), so everything went ok... it seems that the query returned no data, but it did not fail...

Anyway, just as a further check, could you add this more statement before executing mysql_query?

```
echo "SELECT age,wname,slid,sex FROM user WHERE user.c_name='".$coname."'";
```

so we will see what the query looks like...

EDIT3:

please, replace:

```
$coname=$_POST["c_name"];
```

by

```
$coname=$_REQUEST["c_name"];
```

EDIT 4:

```
$bilgi= mysql_query("SELECT age,wname,slid,sex,c_name FROM user");
while($sutun= mysql_fetch_array($bilgi))
{
    echo $sutun["age"];
    echo $sutun["wname"];
    echo $sutun["sex"];        
    echo $sutun["slid"];    
    echo $sutun["c_name"];    
}
```

Comment: well there are alot of countries but it is reading correctly i try nslog after that and it prints corretly if i write the where statement in php side there is no response but if i delete where part (SELECT .. FROM ..)like this it prints correctly third one is variable that i choose the name (I dont know if it matters i choose aaa instead of coname)

Comment: post and get both defined in php if i am not wrong my problem is when i write where part it doesnt respond but if i delete it works so where can be the problem

Comment: please, see my edit... I am not asking about the variable purpose, I am asking about the variable *values*...

Comment: Array
(
    [c_name] => France
)
1<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /vhosts/trevesstudios.com/http/get.php:31) in <b>/vhosts/trevesstudios.com/http/get.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
0:
Array
(
    [c_name] => France
)
 output is this mate

Comment: 2011-07-25 15:08:14.716 APPINESS_V02[4698:707] Array
(
    [c_name] => Turkey
)
1<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /vhosts/trevesstudios.com/http/get.php:31) in <b>/vhosts/trevesstudios.com/http/get.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
SELECT age,wname,slid,sex FROM user WHERE user.cname=''0: there is data for Turkey and it didnt write cname in the field so this is the problem if i am not wrong

Comment: SELECT age,wname,slid,sex FROM user WHERE user.cname='Turkey'0: it gives this at the end but still didnt take the data from server but at least we can see the where statement works

Comment: yeah,very good. I cannot enter into your DB to check whether there are any data, possibly you could check what data are there by using the code in my EDIT4...

Comment: 40 people  school   female8440 people  school   female7140 people  schoolmoney   female8740 people   politics  female3 it does not see c_name damn let me post you a picture for see my database.

Comment: [link](http://postimage.org/image/23f3430p0/) this is my picture from database you can see variables from it

Comment: ah i forget to put c_name to the SELECt part yep it shows the name  thanks mate i figure it out thanks for patience and helping have a really nice day.

Comment: Is the table name really `user`? Are you selecting the correct database? I cannot think of anything else...